# LG Ultrafine 4K display - USB hub turns off when screen turns off / unplugged from MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, display, usb

I have my MacBook plugged into an LG Ultrafine 4K display (as recommended, sold and partially engineered by Apple).

When I unplug my Mac from it the USB hub stops charging devices attached to it. This is ridiculous as I mainly use it as a charging hub.

There is nothing in the manual about this - and I can find nothing on Google.

Is there any way to keep the USB hub powered all the time?

Comment: When you say _or the screen goes off _ do you mean it's gone to sleep, is on standby, or that it's powered off?

Comment: I've rephrased the question - it doesn't matter. When I unplug my monitor from my computer it stops charging USB devices. I want to keep charging those devices.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior.  According the [LG specifications](http://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-27MD5KA-B-5k-uhd-led-monitor) the **maximum** power supplied when in sleep mode is 1.2W and when off is .5W. (This is for the monitor as a whole, not just the USB ports. For this answer, let's assume all of the power is being redirected to the ports - for illustrative purposes only)

Using the formula for watts and converting to solve for Amps,

```
W = V * A  => A = W ÷ V
```

So, assuming that the 5V remains constant, the amps it's supplying is .24A in sleep and .1A off.  For the record, that's not enough to charge a [Nokia 3310](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nokia_3310) from 2000 much less a smartphone from the last 10 years.

The [power requirement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB) for USB 2.0 is to supply upto 500mA (.5A), 3A for USB 3.1 and up to 5A for power delivery (the type C interface).

When you unplug your MacBook from the monitor, it goes into sleep mode and dropping power consumption which ultimately disconnects your devices.

My solution is to purchase an [Anker USB charging hub](http://radnex.us/anker-charging-hubs) that's designed for this type of task. I've purchased this exact charging hub and positioned it at the side of my desk to charge the myriad of devices.  Even when I need to connect my device to my Mac and charge simultaneously, I have a hub that's capable of delivering 10W on the port.

Answer (score 0):

It charge my devices nicely without a connected MacBook, if I am not using a USB-C to USB-C cable. I am using either

- official USB-C to lightning cale
- USB-C to micro USB cable, with micro-USB(female) to lightning/USB-C(male) adapter

If I connect a device via a USB-C to USB-C cable, things just go mess.